# Using ADO VBA to Insert Excel Fields into Access Table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use ADO to access and read some things from an Excel File.  I understand how to get it open and do the SELECT * and put that into a Recordset Object.  What I don't understand is if I am select a group of info, how to access specific fields in that Recordset.

Code:

```
Private Sub SaveReq_Click()
' 
' Saves the current entry to the database
' Into the TABLE 'pr_req_table'
' 

' Open a connection to the database
dim data_base as Database
set data_base = OpenDatabase(CurrentProject.Path & "\test_database.accdb")

Sub InsertRecord()
Dim data_base As Database
Set data_base = OpenDatabase(CurrentProject.Path & "\test_database.accdb")

' Grab all information from form
' Add information to pr_req_table
Dim qd As QueryDef
Set qd = data_base.CreateQueryDef("")
qd.sql = "INSERT INTO pr_req_table(pr_no, pr_date, pr_owner, pr_link, pr_signed) " & _
    "values([p1],[p2],[p3],[p4],[p5])"
qd.Parameters("p1").Value = pr_num.Value
qd.Parameters("p2").Value = Format(pr_date.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
qd.Parameters("p3").Value = List22.Value
qd.Parameters("p4").Value = "Excel Copy #" & elec_copy.Value
qd.Parameters("p5").Value =  "Signed Copy #" & sign_copy.Value 
qd.Execute


' The following section reads from the elec_copy field's hyperlink
' It scans the Excel file for items it needs to include into the table
' It enters those cells into the TABLE 'items_needed_table'
'
' Slects row by row, and if the item has been marked TRUE, inserts
' That row into the TABLE 'items_needed_table'


' Open a connection to Excel
On Error Resume Next

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & elec_copy.Value & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

' Decalre a RecordSet Object
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Grab all Rows in the Plain_VDR Sheet where 'needed' column == TRUE
objRecordset.Open "Select line_no, desc, weeks FROM [Plain_VDR$] Where needed = TRUE", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

' Declare a loop counter for row?
Dim x as Integer
x = 0

' Write the information pulled, into the TABLE 'items_needed_table' in Access Database
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
        qd.sql = "INSERT INTO items_needed_table(pr_no, line_no, desc, weeks) " & _
        "Values([p1],[p2],[p3])"
        ' p1 was declared earlier in code, same value as before
        qd.Parameters("p2").Value = objRecorset.(ROW_X, "line_no")
        qd.Parameters("p3").Value = objRecordset.(ROW_X, "desc")
        qd.Parameters("p4").Value = objRecordset.(ROW_X, "weeks")
        qd.Execute
        x = x + 1
Loop

' Close Database connection
data_base.Close

End Sub
```

My main point of concern is the 'Do Until' loop section.  Doubtful I can insert the entire selection, because 'pr_no' is not defined in the Excel file, but back in Access Database, so I think I will need to loop that command for each row in the Excel file.
What do I need to use to assign my parameters the values, per row and field, from the Recordset Object?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Comment: If pr_no is an autonumber, there is no need to include it. Why are you not either inserting all the data at once through a query or just linking the range as a table in Access and running ordinary enough Access queries?

Comment: pr_no is not an autonumber.  Can't insert all the data at once because I need to assign a pr_no to each line.  The Excel file is different every time a new entry is made, which is why I need to run through it each time a new one is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your connection string, you have said HDR=Yes, which means that the first row of your range contains the names of your fields, so, very roughly:

```
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    qd.Sql = "INSERT INTO items_needed_table(pr_no, line_no, desc, weeks) " & _
    "Values([p1],[p2],[p3])"
    ' p1 was declared earlier in code, same value as before
    '**No it was not, the earlier stuff is mostly irrelevant

    qd.Parameters("p2").Value = objRecorset.Fields("line_no")
    qd.Parameters("p3").Value = objRecordset.Fields("desc")
    qd.Parameters("p4").Value = objRecordset.Fields("weeks")
    qd.Execute
    ''You are moving through a recordset, not a worksheet
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

If this all that you are doing with the selection from Excel, it could be inserted with one query, because you are not changing pr_num.

Comment: Thanks @Remou.  So you are saying that the value of ("p1") is null after the execution command from earlier above?

Comment: It may or may not be, it is a little difficult to unravel :) I thought you had reset the query, but perhaps you did not.